# Solving $\frac{1}{2} < \cos \theta < \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Find the values of theta which satisfy the given condition on a unit circle
>
> $$\frac{1}{2} < \cos \theta < \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

I'm able to plot the points and answer according to me should be $(2n\pi + \frac\pi6, 2n\pi + \frac\pi3)$ which turns out wrong according to my answer key

Comment: Like I said, I am able to plot the values, on unit circle but the answer turns out to be wrong somehow.

Comment: Redraw your unit circle. include values where $\sin\theta$ is negative.

Comment: Recall that $\cos$ is positive also in the fourth quadrant.

Comment: Also be careful with brackets vs parentheses. You inequalities are strict, but that's not reflected in the intervals you've written. (Although I now realize you're not familiar with Mathjax it seems, and may not know how to use "less than or equal to" ...)

Comment: Yes, I see, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

As you know, $cos(\pm\frac\pi6)=\frac{\sqrt3}2$ and $cos(\pm\frac\pi3)=\frac{1}2$. So, the answer should be equal to $$\left( 2n\pi + \frac\pi6,\ 2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{3}\right)\ \cup \left( (2n+1)\pi + \frac{2\pi}3,\ (2n+1)\pi + \frac{5\pi}6\right)$$

Comment: Brackets are wrong I think according to question

Comment: @user354545 Thanks for your comment. I made the required revisions.